# How can I resolve http-conduit issue with Yesod 10.2?

Tags: haskell, cabal, yesod

I have the following problem when running
`yesod devel` in [my application](https://github.com/thlorenz/WebToKindle/tree/yesodsite/src).

It starts out fine (compilation completes), but faults when preprocessing executables:

> Resolving dependencies...
>   Configuring WebToKindle-0.0.0...
>   Rebuilding application...
>   Forcing recompile for ./Model.hs because of config/models
>   Forcing recompile for ./Foundation.hs because of config/routes
>   Forcing recompile for ./Foundation.hs because of messages/en.msg
>   Forcing recompile for ./Foundation.hs because of templates/default-layout-wrapper.hamlet
>   Forcing recompile for ./Foundation.hs because of templates/default-layout.hamlet
>   Forcing recompile for ./Handler/Root.hs because of templates/homepage.hamlet
>   Preprocessing library WebToKindle-0.0.0...
>   Preprocessing executables for WebToKindle-0.0.0...
>   Building WebToKindle-0.0.0...
>
> Application.hs:22:8:
>       Could not find module `Network.HTTP.Conduit':
>         It is a member of the hidden package`http-conduit-1.2.6'.
>         Perhaps you need to add `http-conduit' to the build-depends in your .cabal file.
>         Use -v to see a list of the files searched for. Build failure, pausing...

Running `cabal install` of my application works fine and I am able to launch it and browse to the start page in the browser.

So this problem seems to only occur with the `devel` tool.

I tried to unregister related packages and reinstalled them together in order to help cabal figure out the dependencies.

`cabal install yesod yesod-auth authenticate http-conduit`

Unfortunately that didn't change a thing.

Since I would like to enjoy the benefit of "instant gratification" development I appreciate any help in figuring this out.

**Update**:

After tinkering with things for a while and with monadic's help in zeroing in on the problem source, I figured out that the problem was that I had changed the cabal version inside my cabal file to 1.8. I changed it back to 1.6 and now everything works fine.

Answer (score 2):

[Warning: My advice has nothing to do with Yesod as I don't use it. It might be wrong]

That error is not talking about a missing package in terms of installation. You only have access to the dependencies listed *in your cabal file*, not *the entire package list*. You need to add `http-conduit` to your dependencies (preferably with correct version constraints)

Comment: I wish it was that easy, but it is already listed as a dependency in my cabal file: 
https://github.com/thlorenz/WebToKindle/blob/yesodsite/src/WebToKindle.cabal.

Comment: @Thorsten Lorenz still, it doesn't seem likely that installation is the issue here. However, the package doesn't happen to be hidden by some chance? (Sorry, just throwing out ideas... No knowledge of yesod in particular)

Comment: @Thorsten Lorenz Oh, I took a look at your cabal file - only the executable has it as a dependency, not the library. Perhaps thats the issue? And since the library is only built with `yesod devel` according to the cabal file, this makes a lot of sense.

Comment: Got it I had changed my cabal version to 1.8 changing inside my cabal file. Changing it back to 1.6 fixes things. Thanks for helping me focus on the source of the problem.

Comment: @ThorstenLorenz Doesn't sound like a good fix, imo. Its better to have the dependencies right for 1.8...

Comment: As I said, I believe that my dependencies are correctly defined (e.g., http-conduit is part of declared dependencies).
Yesod auto generates that cabal file and specifies cabal version of 1.6, so messing with it is probably not a good idea. I believe changing it to 1.8 just gets you incompatibility hell that may not even be fixable in the first place (e.g., Yesod must have a reason for specifically requiring cabal version 1.6).